# Stateless widgets are being called multiple times

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-web

I have come across a strange issue. While implementing a functionality, I noticed that all of my **widgets functions** are called continuously, resulting in high CPU consumption. To prevent this, I changed all my widgets functions to **stateless widgets** but unfortunately, the problem still persists. Can anyone guide me as to why this is happening or where I am going wrong?

```
class BearbeitungWidget extends StatelessWidget {
  const BearbeitungWidget({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Consumer<EAProvider>(
      builder: (context, v, child) => Container(
        child: Column(
          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
          children: [
            Visibility(
                visible: v.expandBearWidget,
                child: SizedBox(
                  child: Row(
                    children: [
                      SizedBox(
                        child: Column(
                          children: const [
                            SizedBox(child: Text('Vorgang')),
                            SizedBox(child: Text('Maßnahme')),
                          ],
                        ),
                      ),
                      // this is called multiple times
                      _BearbeitungItemWidget(
                          itemText: 'Technische Prüfung (E)',
                          gridLength: 11,
                          backWidgetColor: const Color.fromRGBO(250, 80, 80, 1),
                          frontWidgetSize: 0.01,
                          includeIcons: true),
                    ],
                  ),
                ))
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class _BearbeitungItemWidget extends StatelessWidget {
  String itemText;
  int gridLength;
  Color backWidgetColor;
  double frontWidgetSize;
  bool includeIcons = false;

  _BearbeitungItemWidget(
      {Key? key,
      required this.itemText,
      required this.gridLength,
      required this.backWidgetColor,
      required this.frontWidgetSize,
      this.includeIcons = false})
      : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    print('_BearbeitungItemWidget CALLED');
    return SizedBox(
      child: Column(
        children: [
          Container(
            child: const Text('Maßnahme'),
          ),
          SizedBox(
            // this is called multiple times
            child: _StackedItemWidget(
                backWidgetColor: backWidgetColor,
                frontWidgetSize: frontWidgetSize,
                includeIcons: includeIcons),
          ),
          // this is called multiple times
          _NumberGridWidget(length: gridLength),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}

class _NumberGridWidget extends StatelessWidget {
  int length;

  _NumberGridWidget({Key? key, required this.length}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    print('_NumberGridWidget CALLED');
    return Container(
      child: Wrap(
        children: [
          for (var i = 0; i < length; i++)
            // this is called multiple times
            _GridItemWidget(
              text: i,
            )
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}

class _GridItemWidget extends StatelessWidget {
  int text;

  _GridItemWidget({Key? key, required this.text}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    print('_GridItemWidget CALLED');
    return Container(
      child: const Text('Maßnahme'),
    );
  }
}

class _StackedItemWidget extends StatelessWidget {
  Color backWidgetColor;
  double frontWidgetSize;
  bool includeIcons = false;

  _StackedItemWidget(
      {Key? key,
      required this.backWidgetColor,
      required this.frontWidgetSize,
      this.includeIcons = false})
      : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    print('_StackedItemWidget CALLED');
    return Stack(
      children: [
        // this is called multiple times
        _StackedChildItemWidget(
            textColor: backWidgetColor,
            width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width * 0.10,
            includeIcons: includeIcons),
      ],
    );
  }
}

class _StackedChildItemWidget extends StatelessWidget {
  Color? textColor;
  double? width;
  bool includeIcons = false;

  _StackedChildItemWidget(
      {Key? key, this.textColor, this.width, this.includeIcons = false})
      : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    print('_StackedChildItemWidget CALLED');
    return Container(
      child: Center(
        child: const Text('Maßnahme'),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Are you sure EAProvider isn't repeately calling notifyListeners for some reason, i don't see anything else wrong here

Comment: @SankethB.K yeah, I guess this might be the issue. Thanks!